# How Can I Get minute() to Return 00 instead of 0?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working on pulling time data from a dttm object in R and formatting it in HH:MM. I have been able to accomplish this using

```
paste(hour(datetime), minute(datetime), sep=':')
```

with one exception: when the minutes are less than 10. When I do this, the minute function just returns the minutes without a leading 0. For example:

```
library(lubridate)

datetime = ymd_hms('2018-11-18 14:00:00')

minute(datetime)
```

This gives an output of

```
> minute(datetime)
[1] 0
```

I believe there are options using hms or other packages/functions, or by building an if-then, but I'd like to minimize dependencies and complexity and stick within the particulars of lubridate to accomplish my goal if at all possible.

(Note: I realize the same issue exists for hour(), but all the times I'm using are PM, so it's not as pressing in my case).

Comment: your data is having 14 hour 0 minutes so obviously it will give minute as 0 change it to 14:30 , it will give you output as 30

Comment: `sprintf("%02d", minute(datetime))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `format` you can get your own custom date format after specifying -

```
> format(datetime, "%M")
[1] "00"
```

**OR**

Thanks @Ronak -

```
> sprintf("%02d", minute(datetime))
[1] "00"
```

Comment: Always amazing what you can achieve with base R!

Comment: @Christoph Amazingly, you can get the hour _and_ the minute with base R.

Comment: Awesome. The second option worked great in the particular script I was running. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing all this extra work? Just get the time directly from your datetime (POSIXct) object.

```
strftime(datetime, "%H:%M")
# [1] "14:00"
```